# Double-counting reputation for migrated questions

Tags: discussion, reputation

Last month I answered a question on MO, which was later migrated to MSE.  Upon migration, the up/down votes for my answer were migrated from MO to MSE.  That makes sense.  What I find strange is that the pre-migration up/down votes for the question are now counted twice, in the question asker's MO and MSE accounts.  Is this intentional and/or desirable?

The question is
[Branch points lie in P^1(Q-bar)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746493/branch-points-lie-in-mathbb-p1-left-overline-mathbb-q-right), asked April 5 on MO and migrated April 9 to MSE.  It received an up and a down vote on April 5, and reputation for those votes currently appears in the asker's
[MO account](https://mathoverflow.net/users/47136/galoisfan?tab=reputation) and
[MSE account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32119/fair-coin-tossing?tab=reputation) (under the April 5 tab).  In addition, the question itself is still listed in the asker's
[MO account](https://mathoverflow.net/users/47136/galoisfan?tab=questions).  By contrast, the reputation earned from the April 5 votes for my answer was eliminated from my 
[MO account](https://mathoverflow.net/users/30412/michael-zieve?tab=reputation) (and moved to my 
[MSE account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/61116/michael-zieve?tab=reputation)) when the question was migrated to MSE on April 9, and the answer is not listed in my 
[MO account](https://mathoverflow.net/users/30412/michael-zieve?tab=answers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original question which was migrated gets automatically deleted after some time, so the reputation is deducted.

What should really bother you is the question what is the voting data that gets migrated. In particular, can I vote your post on MO, and then vote it again on MSE (as the two votes are separate)? *That* would be counting reputation twice, but only on the target site.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess a reason to keep the question at MO for a while is to help people find the pointer to MSE if they've previously noticed the MO question.  I can see some purpose for doing that.  I'll accept your answer once the question is automatically deleted.  Regarding potential double MSE voting: I assume that is handled via a user's network profile, which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: There's another reason. Suppose you migrate a question, and it gets closed. In that case the question is bounced back to the origin site (MO, in this case). But I believe this can only occur within a given timeframe after migration.

Comment: You raise a very interesting question. I may take it up with the devs.

Comment: @Alex: I believe that once I tested that, and I did manage double voting (nothing that wasn't worth the trouble), but it's still worth a look. (I used to have a long list of loopholes in the system that I liked to keep to myself, many are gone by now, though.)